# Django. Confusing query. Count items

Tags: django

I have table cold Mark.

```
class Mark(models.Model):
    media = models.ForeignKey('media.Media')
    mark = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('media_object','user')
```

How can i get query set of media instances (or just count the media) which has at least one vote?

Can i make it whith out using `extra`?

**UPDATED:**
I other words: I'm running through all table and counting all unique media. If i found it second time I'm not counting it. 
Other words: I need count unique media fields.

Comment: How does your Media model looks like? Does it have a field called 'vote'? And do you mean media or mark instances?

Comment: Where does the vote come from?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: By saing - has one vote, I mean that in table there is at least one row of this media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the "Mark" model is how users vote. To get all media models with their mark counts, you need [aggregation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#):

```
from django.db.models import Count

media_with_vote_count = Media.objects.annotate(vote_count=Count('mark_set'))
```

You can then use `filter()` that refers to that annotation:

```
voted_media = media_with_vote_count.filter(vote_count__gt=0)
```

There are also other useful aggregates. For example, you could calculate an average mark for every media:

```
from django.db.models import Avg

media_with_markavg = Media.objects.annotate(average_mark=Avg('mark_set__mark'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    mk = Mark.objects.all()
    mk.media.count()
```

U can use the count function but not sure of ur question what u want to do from it or what is vote..

EDIT:

```
          One row of media

          if( mk.media.count() > 0):
                    ......
```